# How can I give different color for each letter in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input text field like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/q7TVy/),

```css
input {
  color: red
}
```

```html
Name:
<input type="text" name="text" class="text" />
```

I want to apply different color for each letter in the input text field , If the user enters `hai` the each letter `h,a,i` the adjacent letter should have different color .Let me choose red and yellow. Is there  is any way for that in jQuery, css?

Comment: It is not possible with only an `<input>`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : Any other way , something like content editable div

Comment: text in input fields is not stylable to that level. You could use a `contentEditable=true` element, though.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - I don't recommend programmatically wrapping characters in `<span>`s on key press because this will mess up IMEs.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 is there any other way color single letter without wrapping it using any tag

Comment: @PranavCBalan - I don't think there is another way doing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Y8ySy/

```
$("body").prop("contentEditable", true).blur(function(){
    var chars = $(this).text().split("");
    this.innerHTML = "";
    $.each(chars, function(){
        $("<span>").text(this).css({
            color: "#"+(Math.random()*16777215|0).toString(16)  //just some random color
        }).appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

You can actually set the event to `keypress` if the user is only going to enter with a normal keyboard. I used `blur` here because `keypress/keyup` will break the code if the user is entering text with IME.

As [Billy Mathews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655079/283863) mentioned, one might want to have an `input` that can be submitted by `form`. Here is a solution:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenEle">

var chars = $(this).text().split("");
$("#hiddenEle").val($(this).text());
this.innerHTML = "";
```

---

### Just for fun

Here is one that won't change color: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/A7gL2/

Comment: @PranavCBalan - CSS takes in color values in hexadecimal.

Comment: It'd be a real challenge if this was done while typing and colors would remain the same.

Comment: @akinuri - It's not that difficult because you can just select the textnode and wrap it with a new `span`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do right now even though the question is answered =)

Comment: Although.. I always prefer to have things work without dependencies such as a JavaScript library.. or even JavaScript entirely. In my answer the form would still work (hide the text onLoad) where as yours would not ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not make the input's font invisible and have some javascript that dynamically changes some text placed over the input as you type? Something like this:

```
<div>
    Name:<input type="text" name="text" class="text" />
    <div class="colors"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').keyup(function(){
        var output="";
        var letters = $(this).val().split("");
        letters.forEach(function(letter){
            var color = "#"+(Math.random()*16777215|0).toString(16);
            //Stolen from Derek's answer ;)
            output += '<span style="color: ' + color + ';">' + letter + '</span>';
          $('div.colors').html(output);
        });
    });
});
```

Then you just gotta position the div over the input; et voila! <s>Not tested.. but I am making a jsFiddle now!</s> http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/54EY4/6/

Comment: I realise I'm a bit late.. thought I may as well contribute this as you/someone may want to have an input for a form element

Comment: If you put it over then you can't even click on the `input`.

Comment: +1 for your answer, Need to change something then it will work http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/54EY4/6/

Comment: Well done, you managed to fix it quicker than me! 20 minutes quicker.. but it's 4:30AM so I have an excuse.. Goodnight!

Comment: P.S I updated my answer with your jsFiddle for anyone who might come across this

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Fixed the `CTRL+A` `DEL` problem.  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K6ujD/1/)

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.onkeydown = colorTheText;

function generateRandomColor() {
    var color = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        color.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*250));
    }
    return color;
}

function rgbToHex(color) {
    var hex = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        hex.push(color[i].toString(16));
        if (hex[i].length < 2) { hex[i] = "0" + hex[i]; }
    }
    return "#" + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[2];
}

function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

var colors = [];
var inputLength = 0;
var ctrl = [];

function colorTheText(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        if (ctrl.indexOf(17) > -1 && ctrl.indexOf(65) > -1) {
            input.innerHTML = "";
            ctrl.length = 0;
        }
    } else {
        var text = input.innerText;
        if (text.length > inputLength) {
            inputLength++;
            colors.push(generateRandomColor());
        } else {
            inputLength--;
            colors.pop();
        }
        input.innerHTML = "";
        text = text.split("");
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if (colors[i]) {
                input.innerHTML += '<span style="color:' + rgbToHex(colors[i]) + '">' + text[i] + '</span>';
            }
        }
        setEndOfContenteditable(input);        
        if (e.keyCode == 17) {
            ctrl.length = 0;
            ctrl.push(17);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 65) {
            if (ctrl[0] == 17 && ctrl.length == 1) {
                ctrl.push(65);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

---

Even though the question is answered, I wanted to post my answer. Might come handy to future viewers.

In this one color change happens while typing, and it remembers the color order until the div is completely cleared.

And I know it's not perfect. Yet. Play with it.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K6ujD/)

<sub>`setEndOfContenteditable` function taken from [Nico Burn's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866442/2202732)</sub>

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.onkeydown = colorTheText;

function generateRandomColor() {
    var color = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        color.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*250));
    }
    return color;
}

function rgbToHex(color) {
    var hex = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        hex.push(color[i].toString(16));
        if (hex[i].length < 2) { hex[i] = "0" + hex[i]; }
    }
    return "#" + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[2];
}

function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

var colors = [];
var inputLength = 0;

function colorTheText(e) {
    var text = input.innerText;
    if (text.length > inputLength) {
        inputLength++;
        colors.push(generateRandomColor());
    } else {
        inputLength--;
        colors.pop();
    }
    input.innerHTML = "";
    text = text.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (colors[i]) {
            input.innerHTML += '<span style="color:' + rgbToHex(colors[i]) + '">' + text[i] + '</span>';
        }
    }
    setEndOfContenteditable(input);
}
```

Comment: I can't press `Ctrl+A delete` to delete the text. :(

Comment: And also you can do `"#"+(Math.random()*16777215|0).toString(16);` (since color is just a 8 byte integer) to get a random color with fast speed ;)

Comment: I know. That's why I said it's not perfect yet. I'll try to fix that later. Right. Well, I took those color functions from an old project of mine. Didn't want to write again. Lazy me =P

Comment: `CTRL+A DEL` works now. Though I noticed another problem. Can't have line-breaks. I'll get to that later =)

Comment: Nice work. One weird "bug" I found is that as the input gets longer, the speed (fps) becomes exponentially slower. (this reminds me of that boring BigO notation thing...O(n^2)..)

Comment: Just tested. You're right. Like, after 150th~ letter it slows. Well, then let's hope the user doesn't write an article with this :D Though it can be used with short texts.

And damn. This thing is full of bugs. Just found another one. If you `CTRL+A` then cancel the selection, and later hit `del` it deletes the whole text. I gotta clear the `ctrl` array on selection cancelling >.>

Comment: I just made one that won't lag and the color won't change. Can handle Ctrl+A, selections, text pasting... basically just like the normal text input: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/A7gL2/

Comment: (Tested on Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: You did it! Just one feature away from perfect. Line-breaks. Also I'd like if you write this in pure JS sometime. I wanna know what's going on in there. Not that familiar with jQuery, and don't wanna go through the API now.

Comment: Here is the exact same code but with only native methods: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BY399/ (Oh boy, that was scary)

Comment: Haha. Thank you for the effort. Didn't go through your code yet, but noticed a bug. If you follow this `input -> enter(new line) -> CTRL+A DEL -> input` then it gets messy. Checked the jQuery version and it's bug free. It's only in the pure JS version. I think it makes a new line(tho it doesn't work), but caret position breaks or something.

Comment: I tried to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BY399/2/ (I blocked all `<br>` to prevent going into the next line) but the code just gets more messy now

Comment: Well done. I can handle this level of messy :) Btw, I noticed something. `CTRL DEL` deletes the whole text. Though I'm not sure to call this a bug. You could say it's a feature :D

Comment: Yup. A bug? No it's a feature!