# Change background of textarea with limit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea `.txt` which has a limit of 250 char.

I want the background of text getting red if reached >250 char. Just like twitter. But i dont wanna use `contenteditable` div as used by twitter for many reasons.

```
$('.txt').keyup(function{
  if($(this).val().length>250){
  //limit reached now change bg of >250 chars.
}});
```

I only want to change the background of text after 250 characters & not the whole textarea.

Comment: You don't have a choice; with a `textarea` it's all or  nothing.

Comment: What you are referring to @DavidThomas? The background color can be changed on a `textarea`.

Comment: How can it be done without a textarea?

Comment: @BrandonWhite yes but not the background color of the *text*.

Comment: Yes, @Brandon, it can. I never said it *couldn't*. What I *said* was simply that, with a `textarea` element it's the *entirety* of that element that's affected by any change, not a portion of it.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for the reply. See above for the reasoning of my comment.

Comment: How can we change a portion of it ?or do the same by some other means?
@Brandon  ?

Comment: @user3187838 I've read that the JS needed for what you want to do is pretty complex. You sure you don't want to go with `contenteditable`?

Comment: Yes. Can u givevan idea. I can handle any level of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the "user inserted text" in a element ***span class="classError"*** with the style you want, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var max_length = 25;

  $("#editable").on("keyup", function(){


    if( $(this).text().length > max_length){

      $(this).css("color", "red");

      $("#editable").html('<span class="error">' + $("#editable").text() + '</span>');


    } else {

      $(this).css("color", "");     

    }

  });

});
```

- you can find this example jsbin here (http://jsbin.com/nehac/1/) it's just the basic concept needs improvement, but I'm pretty sure you can do the rest!

You'll then have to solve the cursor position, there's a few solutions, like this one ([How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/3866442#3866442))

Hope this helps!