# How to tag words mixed with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I want to tag some words like Facebook when you are posting and tag some people, mixed with text, using jQuery.

This is the example:
[image]

Comment: I think a bit better description is required

Comment: How I can make the same as image? some words are taged anothers not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fl2c0z21ALQin2PuRcft) I believe this to be what you were after!
I have added an array of 3 names ("Dave Smith", "Test User", "Jim Dot") to the top of my script.js file. In reality you would query this from a database and take the top 100 or so elements, in the Facebook example I would say take the top 200 friend names based on total interactions.

My code works for Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 (I have not tested other browsers yet):
[image]

The important code is the div with the contenteditable attribute set to true:

```
<div id="tag-area" class="tag-area" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

And the important JavaScript is this code for searching my array of names and wrapping the text in a "span" element:

```
function ExistsInListOfNamesAndIsNotHiglighted(item) {
   return $("#tag-area").html().indexOf(item) > -1 && $("#tag-area").html().indexOf("<span>" + item + "</span>") === -1;
}

$(function() {
  var tags = ["Dave Smith", "Test User", "Jim Dot"];

  $("#tag-area").keyup(function() {
    $(tags).each(function(index, item) {
      if (ExistsInListOfNamesAndIsNotHiglighted(item)) {
        $("#tag-area").html($("#tag-area").html().replace(item, "<span>" + item + "</span>&nbsp;"));

        cursorToEndOfContentEditable($("#tag-area")[0]);
  }
});
```

The "cursorToEndOfContentEditable" code was taken from Nico Burn's answer on the thread

[How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/)

I have also added a bit of CSS to the span tags which will wrap up the tagged pieces of text:

```
span {
  background-color: #D8DFEA; 
  border:1px solid #7688a4;
}
```

Please let me know how you get on!
And do not hesitate to ask me for any refinements :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use "Mix text tags" option in jquery. Please refer 
https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/

[image]