# Why is text entered into a contenteditable element reversed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, contenteditable

**Describe the issue/behavior that seems buggy**

❌ when typing it adds the text/code in **reverse** when typing.

[image: ezgif-4-883a8c0c6e]

**Sample Code or Instructions to Reproduce**

when using [`contendeditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute in the `<code>` HTML tag element.

```html
<pre>
   <code contenteditable="true"></code>
</pre>
```

with an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event listener

> and using this js library https://highlightjs.org/ for syntax highlighting

```js
const code = document.querySelector("code");

code.addEventListener("input", () => {
    hljs.highlightElement(code); // this came from this js library https://highlightjs.org/
    // other code logic (mostly saving to localStorage)
}
```

> like you saw in every typed letter I will add the highlight functionality,
>
>  but seems that completely breaks the typing direction

> and yes, input events also work for not <input> tags if they have that attribute (contenteditable)
>
>  docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

### source code:

https://jsfiddle.net/20zpL5bk/

---

- also another bug is that we can't go down the line break. (only if there is `hljs.highlightElement(code);`)

✅ here without `hljs.highlightElement(code);` is super fluid and can't do everything (but not syntax highlight):

[image: ezgif com-gif-maker (66)]

> (how can I have fluid, normal writing with also syntax highlighting in real-time (input event)?
>
>  is my code wrong for some reason?)

---

**Expected behavior**

> ✅ how should be: `<div></div>` or `hello world`

> ❌ how it is now: `>vid/<>vid<` or `dlrow olleh`

**Additional context**

I tried to write the code in reverse myself manually `>vid/<dlrow olleh>vid<`,  and yes the highlighting works.
[image]

but the direction is always the wrong way. (also deleting isn't possible)

- another interesting thing is if you copy and paste <kbd>(CTRL+V)</kbd> the correct code `<div>hello world</div>` it works fine. (but still remain in the same line, no multiple lines)
- also the cursor of the input doesn't move with the text but remains at the start

---

### source code:

https://jsfiddle.net/20zpL5bk/

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
let langs = ["html", "css", "javascript"];

let outputs = document.querySelectorAll("code");

outputs.forEach((code, index) => {
  // ✅ make it like input 
  code.contentEditable = "true";
  // ✅ if there is some code from localStorage we add it to the website.
  code.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(`${langs[index]}`) || "";
  // ✅ styling of your library (work great when app start)
  hljs.highlightElement(code);

  code.addEventListener("input", () => {
    localStorage.setItem(`${langs[index]}`, code.innerHTML);
    // ❌ why the typing is reversed here?
    // if the next line isn't there then it work fine, otherwise it will change the values to reversed
    hljs.highlightElement(code);

    // console.log
    // example to type <div></div>
    // what I get >vid/<>vid<
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  --gap: 2vmin;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: var(--gap);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container>* {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

code {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre;
  border: 0.2rem solid;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <span>HTML</span>
      <code class="language-html" style="border-color: orange;"></code>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>CSS</span>
      <code class="language-css" style="border-color: blue;"></code>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>JS</span>
      <code class="language-js" style="border-color: yellow;"></code>
    </div>
  </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/styles/default.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For me it works, i typed hello world and it was in order, i have a SecurityError though because of localStorage, it might prevent your bug from happening

Comment: @Lk77 yes, use this https://jsfiddle.net/20zpL5bk/ for the actual bug... the security thing is only for iframe code snippet on stackOverFlow. isn't the problem here, so pls see https://jsfiddle.net/20zpL5bk/

Comment: The problem is in your input listener, that line cause the bug : `hljs.highlightElement(code);` try to use change event instead

Comment: yes, ok i know that, that line is important for highlighting the code and making it syntax colored. why that line reverse it? https://highlightjs.org/

Comment: it's resetting the input at every character i guess

Comment: @Lk77 so you mean that the cursor at every keypress it moves to the start causing this bug? so we need a way to not reset it or move the cursor to the end?

Comment: I think this function override the value which cause a reset of the cursor position

Comment: @Lk77 thanks, how can not make it override, if you have a answer write it and I will upvote and accept it of course, and thanks!

Comment: I would try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/8126784 to move the caret where it was, which imply that you know where the caret was, don't know if it"s doable, and i don't know if it's still work, it's 2011 afterall. And also it's an input not a code element so perhaps it does not apply here

Comment: don't work, because needs an element node (is good if you want to make the cursor navigate from a tag to another tag), but I want to do something like by index and do `input.length - 1` and move every character (at least go the end). thanks as always I will figure out, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @Lk77 the best solution I found so far and is working https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727327/17716837 simple and modern

Comment: i have a potential solution : https://jsfiddle.net/lk77/v69xgw1n/88/ it works but it's blurry, i guess code and textarea don't have exactly the same style

Comment: I improved it a little : https://jsfiddle.net/lk77/v69xgw1n/114/ but i guess it can happen again if both elements are not on top of each other. And there is still the multiline issue so... not very reliable